# Calculate rank for multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm building a motorsport timing app. As car's race around the track, Users input the split times for each `Car` into the app. The app then ranks each car at each split and displays this in my view.

For example, Car A has a split_1 of 5.00 seconds, split_2 of 15.00 seconds, and split_3 of 25.00 seconds. Car B has a split_1 of 5.50 seconds, split_2 of 14.00 seconds, and split_3 of 23.00 seconds. The ranks displayed in my view for car A would be 1, 2, 2. Car B would be 2, 1, 1.

I wrote an inefficient, database-intensive method to calculate the rank for every single split. Basically the method gets all the split_1 times for every car on the `Timesheet` and places them into a sorted array, then compares the current Car's split_1 to find its position. It does this for every car, and every lap. It's a nightmare.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :laps
end

class Lap < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :car
     belongs_to :timesheet
end

class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :laps
end
```

I know I'm missing an easier, more efficient way to calculate each rank. I'm using Postgres 9.2, and with my limited understanding and experience, I think window functions might offer a solution. Is there another way?

Comment: Nice question. The think keeping me from voting for it, is the missing Postgres version number (which is a common nuisance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE split_times (car TEXT, split INT, "time" INTERVAL);
INSERT INTO split_times VALUES ('A', 1, '00:00:05');
INSERT INTO split_times VALUES ('A', 2, '00:00:15');
INSERT INTO split_times VALUES ('A', 3, '00:00:25');
INSERT INTO split_times VALUES ('B', 1, '00:00:05.5');
INSERT INTO split_times VALUES ('B', 2, '00:00:14');
INSERT INTO split_times VALUES ('B', 3, '00:00:23');
CREATE INDEX split_times_split_and_time ON split_times (split, "time");
```

This will get you the split ranks:

```
SELECT 
   car, split,
   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY split ORDER BY time) AS rank 
FROM 
   split_times;
```

You can use this to get the results per car:

```
WITH x AS (
 SELECT 
    car, split, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY split ORDER BY time) AS rank 
 FROM
    split_times ORDER BY split
 )

SELECT 
   car, ARRAY_AGG(rank) AS ranks 
FROM
   x
GROUP BY car;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/03f3a/1)

Window functions [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html)